# Datastax Enterprise cluster crashes

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have a 3 node datastax enterprise cluster running. Regularly one or more nodes crash, leaving java_....hprof files. It always seems to come down to the Java process running out of heap space, which also seems to be related to a query being started (through Spark) that eats up too much memory.

There is probably something wrong with the setup but I have no real idea where to start looking.

Anyone have any tips on how to make sure that the DataStax Enterprise node does not crash, even when unfriendly queries are started?

Comment: Hprof heap dumps mean you're running out of memory. Have you introspected your heap dump with memory analysis tools? There are a few. How big is your heap? Are you running DSE Search or just Cassandra?

Comment: Just downloaded Eclipse Memory Analyzer and opened one of the hprof dumps. Heap is 8Gb (I think) and the larger part of the allocations are from SSTableSliceIterator. The nodes are running spark/cassandra. No dse search.

Comment: I opened a second heapdump from another node. There the picture is different. Most memory allocated to CompoundSparseCellName and  BufferExpiringCell

Comment: The size of the heap dump is the size of the heap.

Comment: Ok.Tx for clarifying. Size is 8,25Gb.

Comment: 8gb heap is fine. What version of dse / c* are you running? What does your spark workload (that causes the OOM) look like?

Comment: Version info is : [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11.908 | DSE 4.8.2 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3] . Using Spark 1.4.1 . I get this e.g when trying to count all rows in a (large) table. As the cluster is being provisioned a lot of background compaction might be going on as well

Comment: OOM can be caused by bad queries/schema. Among other things using clustering keys to select a whole partition can be dangerous. What is your schema and what are your queries ?
Another dangerous cassandra feature is HintedHandoff. In the cassandra logs files you should see some StatusLogger. Is there any system.hints mentionned ?

Comment: Pretty sure it's because of "bad" queries. Would however be nice that these fail iso bringing down one or more nodes in the cluster. During development, issuing bad queries inadvertently is not such an exceptional thing. No way to avoid that then?

Comment: I had a very instructive webex session with a Datastax engineer, and the bottom line is that the io of the cluster is not able to keep up with the needs.